# C++ Template errors?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to learn how to use templated classes. I've created a simple templated class `numbers` that holds 2 numbers that can be any data type. Then I made a method that returns the bigger number of the two in the object. For some reason I keep getting linker errors though... Here's the errors and code. Not sure what's wrong, Visual Studio didn't underline anything in my code.

[image: unresolved external symbol]

They say "unresolved external symbol" if it's too small to read.

templated.h

```
template <class T>
class numbers {
public:
  numbers(T x, T y);
  T bigger();
private:
  T a, b;
};
```

templated.cpp

```
#include "templated.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
numbers<T>::numbers(T x, T y) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
}

template <class T>
T numbers<T>::bigger() {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "templated.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    numbers <int>pair(1, 2);
    cout << pair.bigger() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not supposed to put template implementations in a cpp/c file. Move them all to your `.h` file.

This is because cpp files are supposed to take functions that compile into implementation libraries (like dll files or compiled objects), while template functions have undefined types (yet), whose types get defined at compile time.

You can, however, put specializations of your template functions in the cpp file, where you specify what types you want to include in your compiled objects.

Comment: Oh okay, so I can't put template class function implementations in a separate file unless I specify what data type the function takes. Is that right?

Comment: You implement templates class in a cpp file if you instantiate the class for every type you'll use. Same for functions.

Comment: Oh so should I not use .h files for templated classes?

Comment: @MattCorby You should ONLY use `.h` files for anything that is template. For both classes or global functions. Specializations (specific types instantiations) go to cpp files.